# Tkinter canvas.create_rectangle four core parameters

Tags: python, tkinter

Which of these four options most accurately represents the four core parameters of the canvas.create_rectangle function?

```
canvas.create_rectangle(left, top, width, height)
canvas.create_rectangle(left, width, top, height)
canvas.create_rectangle(left, top, right, bottom)
canvas.create_rectangle(left, right, top, bottom)
canvas.create_rectangle(left, bottom, width, height)
canvas.create_rectangle(left, width, bottom, height)
```

Comment: `canvas.create_rectangle(left, top, right, bottom)`.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates represent two opposite corners of the rectangle.

From the [canonical tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M155):

> `pathName create rectangle x1 y1 x2 y2 ?option value ...?`
> `pathName create rectangle coordList ?option value ...?`
>
> The arguments *x1*, *y1*, *x2*, and *y2* or *coordList* (which must have four elements) give the coordinates of two diagonally opposite corners of the rectangle (the rectangle will include its upper and left edges but not its lower or right edges).

The tcl code `pathName create rectangle x1 y1 x2 y2` is written in python like this: `canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)`.